# Efficient sum of distributions (mixture distribution) and sampling

Tags: python, probability, random-sampling, sample-statistics

I manage to implement adaptive sampling by drawing samples iteratively from an update distribution which is represented by a mixture of two distributions, such that

$$ρ_{new} = a * ρ_{old} + (1 - a) * ρ_{add}$$

where $ρ_{old}$ is uniform distribution at first iteration and $ρ_{add}$ is always normal distribution.

It goes well on the one dimensional case, a pytorch code for illustrattion is as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.distributions as dist
import numpy as np

def inverse_cdf_sampling(num_samples, cdf, x):
  uniform_samples = torch.rand(num_samples)
  indices = torch.searchsorted(cdf, uniform_samples, right=True)
  sampled_values = x[indices.clamp(max=x.size(0) - 1)]

  return sampled_values.to(device)

def CDF_update(lam, PDF, x):
  asr  =  0.8
  mean, std  =  lam
  new_dist  =  dist.Normal(torch.tensor([mean]), torch.tensor([std]))

  pdf_new  =  torch.exp(new_dist.log_prob(x))

  weighted_sum = asr * PDF + (1 - asr) * pdf_new
  normalized_pdf = weighted_sum / torch.sum(weighted_sum) * x.size(0) / (x[-1] - x[0])

  cdf = torch.cumsum(normalized_pdf, dim=0)
  normalized_cdf = cdf / cdf[-1]

  return normalized_pdf, normalized_cdf

PDF  =  dist.Uniform(torch.tensor([0.1 + 1e-4]), torch.tensor([3]))

x    =  torch.linspace(0.1 + 1e-4, 3, 1000).double()
PDF  =  torch.exp(PDF.log_prob(x))
CDF  =  torch.cumsum(PDF, dim=0)

lambda_val  =  [0, 1]
PDF,CDF     =  CDF_update(lambda_val, PDF, x)

samples     =  inverse_cdf_sampling(100, CDF, x)
```

In this code, I normalize the mixture distribution to ensure CDF within [0,1], and sample inversely from the mixture CDF. However, this trick becomes extremely computational expensive when it comes to the bivariate case:

```
def bivariate_inverse_cdf_sampling(num_samples, cdf, x, y):
    cdf_flattened = cdf.flatten()
    uniform_samples = torch.rand(num_samples)
    indices = torch.searchsorted(cdf_flattened, uniform_samples, right=True)
    indices = indices.clamp(max=cdf_flattened.size(0) - 1)

    rows = indices // y.size(0)
    cols = indices % y.size(0)

    sampled_values_x = x[rows]
    sampled_values_y = y[cols]

    return sampled_values_x.to(device), sampled_values_y.to(device)

def CDF_update_bivariate(mean, cov, PDF, x, y):
    asr  =  0.9
    new_dist = dist.MultivariateNormal(torch.tensor(mean), torch.tensor(cov))

    X, Y = torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
    grid = torch.stack((X.flatten(), Y.flatten()), dim=1)

    pdf_new = torch.exp(new_dist.log_prob(grid)).reshape(500, 500)
    weighted_sum = asr * PDF + (1 - asr) * pdf_new
    normalized_pdf = weighted_sum / torch.sum(weighted_sum) * x.size(0) * y.size(0) / ((x[-1] - x[0]) * (y[-1] - y[0]))

    cdf = torch.cumsum(torch.cumsum(normalized_pdf, dim=0), dim=1)
    normalized_cdf = cdf / cdf[-1, -1]

    return normalized_pdf, normalized_cdf

x = torch.linspace(0.1 + 1e-4, 3, 500).double()
sk_max  =  np.exp(3 * 0.01 / np.sqrt(1 - 0.8**2))
sk_min  =  np.exp(-3 * 0.01 / np.sqrt(1 - 0.8**2))
y = torch.linspace(sk_min, sk_max, 500).double()
X, Y = torch.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')

area = (x[-1] - x[0]) * (y[-1] - y[0])
PDF  = torch.full(X.shape, 1.0 / area)

cdf_x = (X - x[0]) / (x[-1] - x[0])
cdf_y = (Y - y[0]) / (y[-1] - y[0])
CDF   = cdf_x * cdf_y

mean        =  [0, 0]
cov         =  [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
PDF,CDF     =  CDF_update_bivariate(mean, cov, PDF, x, y)

sp1,sp2  =  bivariate_inverse_cdf_sampling(100, CDF, x, y)
```

So I wonder is there any solution to make distribution update and sampling efficient and easy to compute?

Comment: I don't understand your code but this is partly due to the fact that I don't know pytorch. What is your bivariate inverse cdf sampling method? I've never heard about such a method. And a question: when $\rho_{\text{old}}$ is picked at the update (with probability $a$), does that mean that you use the previously sampled value?

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent, thanks for the comment. The listed code is very much the same as numpy version if you replace torch. with np. As to the inverse sampling, it stays the same as the one-dimensional case, which use uniform distribution to generate probability within [0,1] and use cdf to track back the associated variable. And of course, it works on bivariate case due to the two variables are assumed to be independent. I also wonder is there any advance or efficient way to inverse sampling on bivariate case?

Comment: And last but not the least, samples be drawn from $\rho_{old}$ and measured by a loss function, and using loss function further generate/or back out $\rho_{add}$, it updates the distribution in an incremental way. Moreover, I normalize pdf in each iteration so the sample value will be new.